# xargs: php: No such file or directory

Tags: php, shell, syntax, xargs

I'm using this command to syntax check every `*php` file it can find.

`find ../src -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 php -l`

But I keep getting this error:

`xargs: php: No such file or directory          write /dev/stdout: broken pipe`

When executing, I'm in a folder like this:

```
root
├── src    
├── scripts
|   ├── main.sh
```

If I `cd` into the root folder and execute the same, but with `./src` instead of `../src`, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you give an absolute path `/root` ? The [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) encourages this: `it is generally safer to prefix wildcards or dubious path names with either ./ or to use absolute path names starting with /.`

Comment: Sadly I just get this error: `find: ‘/root’: No such file or directory

Comment: The issue here is `php` cannot be found. Again, use its absolute path - you can find it using `which php`. Your command should look like: `find /root -name "*.php" -print0|xargs -0 -n1 -P8 /usr/bin/php -l` (or just `[...] -P8 $(which php) -l` if you're running it from the terminal manually)

Comment: I guess what you describe is exactly problem. Thank you so far :)
I've concealed the information, that all of this needs to run within a docker container. I guess all I have to do now, is to find out, where php lies within the container.

Comment: It will be the same, use `docker exec` with user `root` (`-u root`) or create a bash script and volume it to the container. If it is different, simply use `docker exec -u root <container_name_or_id> "which php"` and update the path to the `php` binary. If you do this manually, you could just instance a shell into the container and run it manually: `docker exec -it -u root <container_name_or_id> /bin/bash` and then run your command.

Comment: I've gotten everything up and running now. The only problem is, that I still have `$(which php)` in my script like this: `find ./src -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 $(which php) -l`.
I went into the php container and the return of `which php` gives me `/usr/local/bin/php`. But when I replace it in the script, it keeps throwing this error:
`xargs: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
                                                    write /dev/stdout: broken pipe`

Comment: Perhaps the user you're trying to use doesn't have permission on the binary. Are you using `root`?

Comment: Not using root, I have decided to go with the flow and use $(which php) in production. I still have to thank you very much for your help :)